# change single element to multiple elements

Tags: python-3.x

I need to change a single element in the list to multiple elements in Python 3.x.  for example,

From:

```
list = ['AAA\nBBB\nCCC\nDDD\n']
```

To:

```
list = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD']
```

I don't want to sound rude, but please only reply if you can add value. No unhelpful commentaries.

Comment: `list` is a built-in type. It is good practice to use another name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use split:

```
l = ['AAA\nBBB\nCCC\nDDD\n']
l[0].strip().split("\n")
```

Comment: why does it add ' ' at the end of the list?  ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', ' ']